# Matching stand-alone substrings in Swift

Tags: ios, regex, string, swift, nsstring

I want to check if a string is part of another string but only as a standalone term, not as part of another word. I am working in Swift.

E.g. Here's what I would expect checking for **"mon"**

- "Mon" *true*
- "mon" *true*
- " Mon" *true*
- " Mon " *true*
- "Monday" *false*
- "Monster" *false*
- "Hormons" *false*

What's a good way to do this? (going back and forth between NSString functions like *containsString* and Regular Expressions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use word boundaries with case insensitive modifier.

```
"(?i)\\bmon\\b"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dF4gU2/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\bmon\\b", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: nil)!

func isMatch(str: String) -> Bool {
    return regex.firstMatchInString(str, options: nil, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.utf16Count)) != Optional.None
}

["Mon", "mon", " Mon", " Mon " , "Monday", "Monster", "Hormons"].map(isMatch)

// yields [true, true, true, true, false, false, false]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works with Swift 2.

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\bmon\\b", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)



func isMatch(str: String) -> Bool {
  return regex.firstMatchInString(str, options: .ReportCompletion ,  range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.characters.count)) != Optional.None
}

["Mon", "mon", " Mon", " Mon " , "Monday", "Hormons"].map(isMatch)

// Yields [true, true, true, true, false, false]
```